Query Students with 3 Consecutive Absences - Custom Calendar
Working on identifying students that have 3 or more consecutive absences on a custom calendar (already created) for the school year.
I have a temp table for the custom calendar here:
SELECT 
    cal.CAL_DATE
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cal.SCHOOL_YEAR_GU ORDER BY cal.CAL_DATE asc) rn 
INTO 
    #ITM_CAL 
FROM 
    Rev.EPC_SCH_ATT_CAL cal 
    JOIN rev.REV_ORGANIZATION_YEAR oy ON cal.SCHOOL_YEAR_GU = oy.ORGANIZATION_YEAR_GU 
    JOIN rev.REV_YEAR yr ON oy.YEAR_GU = yr.YEAR_GU 
WHERE 
    cal.ROTATION = 'I' 
    AND yr.YEAR_GU = (SELECT YEAR_GU FROM rev.SIF_22_Common_CurrentYearGU) 


    I have a second temp table for the student absences, joining second temp table to first.


 SELECT
        enr.STUDENT_SCHOOL_YEAR_GU
        , FORMAT (att.ABS_DATE, 'MM/dd/yyyy') AS 'AbsDate'
        , abscd.ABBREVIATION
        , cal.rn
    INTO 
        #ITM_ABS
    FROM
        Rev.EPC_STU_ENROLL enr .....
    
    ......
    And Main query here...
    
    SELECT
      org.ORGANIZATION_NAME AS School
    , stu.SIS_NUMBER AS PermID
    , per.LAST_NAME + ', ' + per.FIRST_NAME AS Name
    , grd.VALUE_DESCRIPTION AS Grade
    , abs.AbsDate AS 'Absent Date'
    
    FROM rev.EPC_STU stu
    JOIN rev.REV_PERSON per ON stu.STUDENT_GU = per.PERSON_GU
    .......
    WHERE
    ssy.STATUS IS NULL
    AND yr.YEAR_GU =` (SELECT YEAR_GU FROM rev.SIF_22_Common_CurrentYearGU)

I want to use the ISLANDS technique to
export students showing
the number of consecutive absent dates (MIN 3),
and create a column showing the absent dates.

Can you have an example here with sample data? https://www.db-fiddle.com/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20402089/detect-consecutive-dates-ranges-using-sql

@PauloFernando thank you, I updated my question.  The original post wasn't written very well.  Thank you!

I take it that this is going to be limited to running for a single school year?

Correct, @shawnt00.

Assuming your calendar and absences queries as the starting point. (Also assuming that PermID represent a student id number.) You just need add a row number to the absences side and join on the common dates. You appear to have intended that school days will be numbered consecutively so that absences across weekends and holidays will be treated part of the same run of dates. The runs will then have a common difference across the row numberings which is the prototypical version of the gaps and islands problem:
with calendar as (
    SELECT 
          cal.CAL_DATE
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cal.SCHOOL_YEAR_GU
                             ORDER BY cal.CAL_DATE asc) rn
    FROM Rev.EPC_SCH_ATT_CAL cal
    JOIN rev.REV_ORGANIZATION_YEAR oy ON cal.SCHOOL_YEAR_GU = oy.ORGANIZATION_YEAR_GU
    JOIN rev.REV_YEAR yr ON oy.YEAR_GU = yr.YEAR_GU
    WHERE cal.ROTATION = 'I'
    AND yr.YEAR_GU = (SELECT YEAR_GU FROM rev.SIF_22_Common_CurrentYearGU) e
), absences as (
    SELECT 
          org.ORGANIZATION_NAME AS School 
        , stu.SIS_NUMBER AS PermID
        , row_number() over (partition by PermID order by att.ABS_DATE) as rn
        , per.LAST_NAME + ', ' + per.FIRST_NAME AS Name 
        , grd.VALUE_DESCRIPTION AS Grade
        , att.ABS_DATE
        , abscd.ABBREVIATION 
     FROM rev.EPC_STU stu 
     JOIN rev.REV_PERSON per ON stu.STUDENT_GU = per.PERSON_GU
     WHERE ssy.STATUS IS NULL 
     AND yr.YEAR_GU = (SELECT YEAR_GU FROM rev.SIF_22_Common_CurrentYearGU)
)
select PermID, count(*) as num_consecutive_absence,
    min(ABS_DATE) as first_absence, max(ABS_DATE) as last_absence
from absences a inner join calendar c
    on CAL_DATE = ABS_DATE
group by PermID, c.rn - a.rn
having count(*) >= 3;

Or referencing the two materialized temp tables:
select PermID, count(*) as num_consecutive_absence,
    min(ABS_DATE) as first_absence, max(ABS_DATE) as last_absence
from (select *,
          row_number() over (partition by PermID order by ABS_DATE) as rn
      from #ITM_ABS) a inner join #ITM_CAL c on CAL_DATE = ABS_DATE
group by PermID, c.rn - a.rn
having count(*) >= 3;

https://dbfiddle.uk/teaSS-kw

Thank you sir.  I am going to edit my question to make it clearer.  I apologize for the confusion.  Newbie here.

@Jesse, nothing changes with my answer as far as I can  tell. You just insert whatever two queries you have that work to return the consecutively numbers school days and absence data and it should work just fine.
